# Android Studio Button command

Tags: java, android

I've created a string which is a random string from an array. The user presses a button and the function executes again, showing the user a new string from the array.

This is what I have thus far, which doesn't quite work:

```
String[] letters = {"s", "a"};
    String randomSad = (letters[new Random().nextInt(letters.length)]);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview11);
    tv1.setText(randomSad);
```

Comment: Add your existing code.

Comment: This is the basic code where get a random letter. Now I want to add a button that erases the previous random, and executes a new.

Comment: I have edited my answer, and posted what you require. Please check it. It is the last bit of code. If that is your required answer, please accept it as the accepted answer. Helps me, and future users. Thank You. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Always provide the code that you have already tried. But this being a simple implementation, it should look like this :**

```
String[] nameList = {"Sam", "Harry", "Ron"}; //Store the list as you like
int index i = 0;    

//put the correct id of the TextView from the xml file
TextView nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

//put the correct id of the Button from the xml file
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

//set the OnclickListener and define what you want to happen in the onClick() method

button.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener() {
    nameTextView.setText(nameList[index]); //set the name in the index as text
    if((index+1) >= nameList.length)
        index++; //increase the index by 1, for the next time.
    else
        index = 0; // to loop back to the first name.
});
```

If you want the last name to stay even if the butten is pressed again, cut out the else part.

**Edit :**
()After you provided the code

```
String[] letters = {"s", "a"};
String randomSad = (letters[new Random().nextInt(letters.length)]);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview11);
tv1.setText(randomSad);

 button.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener() {
    randomSad = (letters[new Random().nextInt(letters.length)]);
    tv1.setText(randomSad); //set the name in the index as text
});
```

Comment: you have to also check if the `index>lengthOfArray` then set the value of index to 0. And make your `index` declaration correct.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention, though it will throw an error as soon as index == lengthofarray. because, at that position, nothing is there. the last element is at length-1. Nevertheless, I have made the correction.